# How to fix LateInitializationError about non-nullable variables?

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, aws-amplify, dart-null-safety

I was studying with an AWS tutorial however, that tutorial is not null safety.
I'v tried to convert it, but is showing:
LateInitializationError: Field '_credentials@26120019' has not been initialized.

I think that "late" modifier is not initializing the variables when I try to get the values in verifyCode

Pleease, how can I  fix the  code below

```
enum AuthFlowStatus {login, signUp, verification, session}

class AuthState {
  final AuthFlowStatus? authFlowStatus;
  AuthState({this.authFlowStatus});
}

class AuthService {
  final authStateController = StreamController<AuthState>();
  late AuthCredentials _credentials;



  void showSignUp() {
    final state = AuthState(authFlowStatus: AuthFlowStatus.signUp);
    authStateController.add(state);
  }

  void showLogin() {
    final state = AuthState(authFlowStatus: AuthFlowStatus.login);
    authStateController.add(state);
  }

  
  void loginWithCredentials(AuthCredentials  credentials) async {
    try {
      
      final result = await Amplify.Auth.signIn(
        username: credentials.username, password: credentials.password,
      );
      
      if (result.isSignedIn) {
        final state = AuthState(authFlowStatus: AuthFlowStatus.session);
        authStateController.add(state);
      } else {
        
        print('User could not be signed in');
      }
    } on AuthException catch (authError) {
      print('Could not login - ${authError}');
    }
  }
  
  void signUpWithCredentials(SignUpCredentials credentials) async {
    try {
      
      Map<CognitoUserAttributeKey, String> userAttributes = {
        CognitoUserAttributeKey.email: credentials.email,

      };
      
      final result = await Amplify.Auth.signUp(
        username: credentials.username,
        password: credentials.password,
        options: CognitoSignUpOptions(
            userAttributes: userAttributes
        ),
      );

      
      if (result.isSignUpComplete) {
        loginWithCredentials(credentials);
      } else {
        
        this._credentials = credentials;


      }
      
      final state = AuthState(authFlowStatus: AuthFlowStatus.verification);
      authStateController.add(state);

      
    } on AmplifyException catch (authError) {
      print('Failed ro sign up - ${authError}');
    }
  }

  
  void verifyCode(String verificationCode) async {
    try {
      
      final result = await Amplify.Auth.confirmSignUp(
        username: _credentials.username,
        confirmationCode: verificationCode,

      );
      
      if (result.isSignUpComplete) {
        loginWithCredentials(_credentials);

      } else {        
        //not implemented yet
      }

    } on AuthException catch (authError) {
      print('Could not verify code - ${authError}');
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: you need to initialize it before it gets called.

Comment: As @Mahi said, you have assigned a value to `_credentials`, before calling a method that uses it.
But in anyways, `_credentials` should be a nullable property rather than a later-initializer. 'Cause that means - "I'm creating it now, but I have no value to assign, so I'll do it later"

Comment: Thank you @0110100101110011 and @Mahi, but I found another solution, I took off the "late".
`AuthCredentials? _credentials;`

and where it is not able to be null I use `_credential!`